# Conversion from epoch time to (dd/mm/yyyy) date format

Tags: discrete-mathematics, programming, unit-of-measure, calendar-computations

The title pretty much explains my problem.
I´m given the number of seconds that have passed since the 1st of January 1970 and I have to return today´s date in (dd/mm/yyyy) format.

I know how to calculate the current year, so the hard part is calculating the current month and day. As I need to find a way of knowing if a month is 28,30 or 31 days long and find a way of, when a year is complete, passing from month 12 to month 1

Comment: This is more of a programming question than a math question. Have you tried asking this on Stack Overflow?

Comment: I was given this problem as an extra activity in my discrete mathematics class but i guess it´s more of a programming cuestion yes. I will try asking it there

Comment: [$30$ days hath September](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thirty_Days_Hath_September), April, June, and November.  All the rest have $31$ except for February

Answer (score 1):

I will denote the epoch time $E$. you know that the days passed since 01/01/1970 is going to be:
$$d=\left\lfloor \frac{E}{86400} \right\rfloor$$
now for the years:
$$y=\left\lfloor\frac{d}{365.25}\right\rfloor$$
now the first leap year in epoch was 1972, so the number of leap years can be represented by:
$$L=\left\lfloor\frac{y-2}{4}\right\rfloor$$
from this and the number of years you can work out if the current year is a leap year, making an algorithrm to change the days in february whether it is or not, then just have a search function for the months like:
$$1\le d_y<31\implies m=\text{jan}$$ etc.

Comment: This will fail in $2100$, which is not a leap year (the first such year since $1900$).

Comment: This will (currently) be off by 27 seconds, since 27 leap seconds have occurred since 1970 ;-)